# change JS object value to key/value

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I want to change the Product* value be a key/value pair (Product: Product*) and each one to be its own object.

Input:

```
[
  "ProductA": {
    "Available": true,
    "Customers": "non-registered"
  },

  "ProductB": {
    "Number": 0
  },

  "ProductC": {
    "Number": 10,
    "Available": false,
    "Customers": "registered"
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "Product": "ProductA",
    "Available": true,
    "Customers": "non-registered"
  },
  {
    "Product": "ProductB",
    "Number": 0
  },
  {
    "Product": "ProductC",
    "Number": 10,
    "Available": false,
    "Customers": "registered"
  }
]
```

Comment: note that your desired output is impossible, it's not valid json or a valid object: the outer object must be an array if you want to have unnamed objects in it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the resulting objects in an array, you can do this with a simple `.map()` using `Object.keys()`:

```js
const data = { "ProductA": { "Available": true, "Customers": "non-registered" }, "ProductB": { "Number": 0 }, "ProductC": { "Number": 10, "Available": false, "Customers": "registered" } };

let result = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({Product: key, ...data[key]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.entries to get the key value pair, and then map it to match to your desired output properties.

```
var prod = {
  "ProductA": {
    "Available": true,
    "Customers": "non-registered"
  },

  "ProductB": {
    "Number": 0
  },

  "ProductC": {
    "Number": 10,
    "Available": false,
    "Customers": "registered"
  }
};

const mappedProduct = Object.entries(prod).map(([key, value]) => {
  return {
    product: key,
    ...value
  }
});

console.log(mappedProduct);
```

Comment: With arrow functions implicit return you can shorten your map function to: `([key, value]) => ({ product: key, ...value })`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, without requiring **Object.entries**

```js
const obj = {
  "ProductA": {
    "Available": true,
    "Customers": "non-registered"
  },

  "ProductB": {
    "Number": 0
  },

  "ProductC": {
    "Number": 10,
    "Available": false,
    "Customers": "registered"
  }
}

const res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({
  Product: key,
  ...obj[key]
}))
console.log(res)
```